# Could not find a declaration file for module '@hookform/resolvers/zod'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zod

Im trying to use zod with react-hook-form but the import hook form resolver gives the error below

> Could not find a declaration file for module '@hookform/resolvers/zod'. '/pradeep/projects/react/safe-zone/node_modules/@hookform/resolvers/zod/dist/zod.mjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.

[image]

Comment: https://arunmichaeldsouza.com/blog/aliasing-module-paths-in-node-js

Comment: you can try adding a paths configuration in your package.json file to create an alias for the module import.

Comment: "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@hookform/resolvers/zod": ["./node_modules/@hookform/resolvers/zod/dist/zod.mjs"]
  }
}

Comment: I tried this but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved by running the below cmd

```
npm i -save-dev @hookform/resolvers
```

Comment: now will the build will be created? as we have installed it in dev dependency? issues in production?